# Passing Datatable item in xpath and getting error "javascript error: arguments[0].scrollIntoView is not a function"

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, automation, specflow, scenarios

Hello I am new to c# and specflow.

I have a scenario outline with 1 datatable

```
Examples:
    | Name    | ID           | Attendence| Date       |
    | Shan    | 1003 - Shan  | FT        | 10/22/2021 |
    | Sam     | ZYZ          | FT        | 10/22/2021 |
```

The above is my code (Page)

```
 IList<IWebElement> AllList = new List<IWebElement>(driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//*[@id='Myul']/li"))); //get all elements in the list

 var path = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[contains(text(),'" + ID + "')]"));
 IJavaScriptExecutor je = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;

 je.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(false);", AllList.Contains(path));
 Thread.Sleep(2000);

 if (path.Displayed)
 {
     path.Click();
 }
```

I am trying to pass the ID I have set in the Feature file, into the xpath but I am getting the following error:

> OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: 'javascript error: arguments[0].scrollIntoView is not a function

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AllList.Contains(path)` returns a boolean value. This is the context of the call to `arguments[0].scrollIntoView(false);` which means JavaScript is attempting to execute `scrollIntoView(false);` on a true/false value instead of an [HTMLElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement) object.

The `AllList.Contains(path)` method just tests to see if `path` is one of the items in the `AllList` collection. It doesn't quite make sense with what you are trying to accomplish. You probably only need to pass `path`:

```
je.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(false);", path);
```

Since `path` is an `IWebElement` in C#, JavaScript will interpret that as the HTMLElement object pointing to the same HTML tag that your IWebElement refers to in C#. This is the context for the call to `arguments[0].scrollIntoView(false);` which executes [HTMLElement.scrollIntoView(boolean)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView). I believe this to be the JavaScript method you are trying to call.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation, it is very helpful and It's working now. Indeed, I just wanted to get the path.